# Content not showing on profile.jsp because of web.xml?

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, web.xml

I have one page: profile.jsp and two controllers: WorkController.java and GebruikerController.java.
From my profile.jsp I request two things:

The user information from GebruikerController.java:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${gebruikers.size() != 0}">
        <!-- Wanneer er gebruikers opgeslagen zijn, worden ze hier getoond -->
        <c:forEach var="tempGebruiker" items="${gebruikersUitSessie}">
            <!-- Per gebruiker wordt nu een rij aangemaakt met daarin zijn gegevens -->
            <div id="main_inner_left">
                <img src="${tempGebruiker.imageURL}" width="150" height="150">
            </div>
            <div id="main_inner_right">
                <table border="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            ${tempGebruiker.firstName} ${tempGebruiker.lastName}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            E-mail: 
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            ${tempGebruiker.email}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Date of birth:
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            ${tempGebruiker.birthDay}-${tempGebruiker.birthMonth}-${tempGebruiker.birthYear}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Gender:
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            ${tempGebruiker.gender}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Country:
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            ${tempGebruiker.country}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            City:
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            ${tempGebruiker.city}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="profile/wijzig?id=${tempGebruiker.userNumber}">Edit profile</a>
                            <!--<a href="javascript:if(confirm('Weet u het zeker dat u deze gebruiker wil verwijderen?'))
                               window.location='profile/verwijder?id=${tempGebruiker.userNumber}';">Verwijder</a>-->
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </c:forEach>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <!-- Als er geen gebruikers zijn, wordt deze melding getoond -->
        Er zijn geen gebruikers gevonden.
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

And the user work experience from the WorkController.java:

```
<c:forEach var="tempWork" items="${workUitSessie}">
    <table border="0">
        <tr>
            <td>
                ${tempWork.fromYear}-${tempWork.tillYear}
            </td>
            <td>
                ${tempWork.name}
            </td>
            <td>
                ${tempWork.profession}
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Description:
            </td>
            <td>
                ${tempWork.description}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</c:forEach>
```

Both of the codes above are located in my profile.jsp.

The problem is that whenever I go to the profile.jsp page on my browser, /profile link is shown in the link tab and it only shows the user information (first code). And whenever I am on my profile.jsp page on my browser, and I change /profile to /work manually in the link tab, it only shows the work experience information.

web.xml:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>GebruikerController</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>controllers.GebruikerController</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>GebruikerController</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/profile</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
        <servlet-name>WorkController</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>controllers.WorkController</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>WorkController</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/work</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

How can I show both at the same time on profile.jsp? Like can I for example request two controllers at the same time? e.g.

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>GebruikerController</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>controllers.GebruikerController + controller.WorkController</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>GebruikerController</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/profile + /work</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Sorry I could not understand your requirement.Please be more clear

Comment: Is my question better now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most certainly you want one Servlet per JSP which then acts as a main controller to init other classes and stuff. Those retrieve data and set it to your JSP.

They way you define it in your web.xml (two different URLs) is thought to differ betrween things so whatever you do only one servlet instance will be called per URL.

So you probably want to create a bean ProfileInformationHolder or something like that which is able to hold the information (lets say Person-objects that each of it has a reference to WorkExperience-object). 
Then have one Servlet gathering the information from two classes (id modify the current Controllers) and prepare the ProfileInformationHolder bean. Once this is done you forward the ProfileInformationHolder bean to your jsp where you can iterate over all information and display them in one place under one url.

**Update:**

Such a java bean is no big story. They basicially just consist of variables and get and set to access them.

So a bean Person could look like this:

```
    public class MyPersonBean {

        private String name = "";

        public String getName(){
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name){
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
```

(Sorry i dont know how to format source and im quite frustrated to spend hours to try to archive what worked for years by copy&paste from my IDEs).

I recomend you do a short tutorial on the topic, something like this http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=552 (not verified) or anything else that comes up by searching "java jsp servlet bean". You will get into it quite fast ;)

Comment: That sounds good, is this something I could use? 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans

Comment: No worries, youre very welcome. Back in the days i used it i always thought of things like "beans", "servlets", "forwarding" and stuff of very complex processes going on but as soon as you have a running example from one of those tutorials out there you will see that it is acctually pretty easy :)